# Finding global extrema

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[Click here for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S9GG.jpg)

I don't know how to find the global extrema of this since taking the partial derivatives with respect to x and y leaves me with no x and y's to find zeros of the function. Please help

Comment: If there are no critical points in the interior, check the boundary.  In fact, always check the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In calc 1, how did you find extrema?  You took the derivative of the objective function, found where it is zero, or where the derivative was undefined.  Then you checked the endpoints.

Now you have a second variable to work with.  You are going to do the same thing.  Take the derivatives, look for where they are zero, then check the boundary.

The partial derivatives $q(x,y)$ are defined everywhere and never zero.  So, we jump to the boundary.

A couple ways to go here:

One is to parameterize the boundary.
$x = \frac 12 \cos t\\ y = \sin t$

$q(t) = 4\cos t + 3\sin t$ and find $t$ to maximize and minimize $q.$

$q(\arctan \frac {3}{4}) = 5\\
q(\arctan \frac {3}{4}+\pi) = -5$

Another would be something along the lines of a Lagrange multiplier

$\nabla (8x + 3y) = \lambda \nabla (4x^2 + y^2 - 1)\\
(8,3) = \lambda (8x, 2y)\\
x = \frac {1}{\lambda}\\
y = \frac {3}{2\lambda}$

Constrained by $4x^2 + y^2 = 1$

$\frac {4}{\lambda^2} + \frac {9}{4\lambda^2} = 1\\
16 + 9 = 4\lambda^2\\
\lambda = \pm \frac {5}{2}\\
x = \pm \frac {4}{5}\\
y = \pm \frac {3}{5}\\
q(\frac {4}{5},\frac {3}{5}) = 5\\
q(-\frac {4}{5},-\frac {3}{5}) = -5$

Comment: I hadn't considered lagrange multipliers. I'm going to work through it before I read to far down on what you've written. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use calculus to solve this problem, you should use Lagrangian multiplier. Otherwise, you can use basic geometry to solve this problem since the extreme values must occur when the line is tangent on the ellipse. The extreme values here can also be found quickly by Schwart Inequality as
$$(8x+3y)^2\le [(2x)^2+y^2][4^2+3^2]=25.$$